# Upload colab notebook to github gives "\n" on all lines when viewed through github

Tags: github, google-colaboratory, git-commit, ipynb

So today I added a new section to my colab notebook and pushed my notebook to github but then when I viewed it all it showed was "\n" on all lines except for a few. You can see it [here](https://github.com/SajawalHassan/sentiment_analysis_pytorch/blob/main/sentiment_analysis_pytorch.ipynb).

This was done through colab method (save a copy on github way) as well as downloading the file and then uploading it. All it showed was "\n".

Viewing the file through the github vs code editor gives me the correct output so I am really confused as to what to do. I have tried searching on the internet for this but had no luck.